# Should I include reference section on a conference poster?

Tags: citations, poster

I believe that including references is important, especially for a chemistry conference poster. However, I have more than two dozens of citations so it is way too lengthy.

Should I still include the reference section or should I simply explain when asked?

Answer (score 3):

Biologist here.

I tend to be more careful to cite *methodology* on a poster rather than things that belong in an introduction or discussion section, and especially anything derived directly from a particular paper, such as an equation that is on the poster.

Sometimes there is a particular key reference - either a review or highly relevant original paper - to cite for background. Otherwise, if you find yourself citing a lot of things you probably have too much text on the poster.

(to be clear: if it needs to be cited, it should be cited; it just turns out that the type of content that needs to be cited should be at a minimum on a poster)

Comment: "it just turns out that the type of content that needs to be cited should be at a minimum on a poster" - yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should have references.  (Unless chemistry is *really* different from other disciplines.)  But it is probably acceptable to make it a pretty short section, and perhaps refer to another document if asked for more details.

In particular, are there 2-3 most important references you could cite in "short format" with "et al." to make them short enough to not distract?  That might be a good middle ground.  Alternately, you could do inline citations for the most important ones, with or without footnotes.

---

(But as always, different disciplines have different standards, so you might want to double check with a few other chemists with a lot of experience presenting posters in the event none of them post an answer here.)

Comment: I'm not in chemistry, but if I saw 5 citations on a poster that would seem too much

Answer (score 1):

CS/AI: I absolutely don’t cite anything beyond the bare minimum and place citations in tiny font at the bottom. The point of the poster is to get people to *read your paper*. They need to get the TL;DR version of it on the way to get tea and cookies, and your poster needs to be more interesting than the robocup tournament. Put the main message in a few sentences, highlight the most interesting things in bold colors and large fonts (think accident lawyer billboards). If anyone asks you about references, give them a copy of the paper (print out a few copies to hand out on the spot).

Comment: Just as a commentary on the heterogeneity of academia, this wouldn't work in other fields, as posters are usually done on new or in-progress findings well before a paper is published.